# Finding best path through set of many points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: point, arcgis-pro, path

Assume I have many points, say 100 or more, that represent a station to visit.  I want to choose one of them as a starting point, and then navigate to each and every one thereafter to take a sample of something.  Essentially looking to create a table to list out and order the stations to  visit based on the shortest path from a particular starting point that I choose.

The points are not one a road or line or any but transit sort of problem, but are merely random places in say, a forest.  In sum, looking for way to choose one to start out and then navigate (walk) to each one thereafter by a shortest distance.  Forget the ups and downs, not important.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Python with pandas and networkx modules:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import math

#Create a pandas dataframe using da.SearchCursor
layer = "points_to_visit" #The name of your point layer
fields = ["OID@","SHAPE@X","SHAPE@Y"]
data = [[row[0], row[1], row[2]] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, fields)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["id","x","y"])

#df is a table of point id, x and y coordinates
#df.head(1)
#id x   y
#1  583821.3902 6.810667e+06

df = df.merge(df, how="cross") #Cross join each point to all others
df = df.loc[df["id_x"]!=df["id_y"]] #Drop self joins

#Calculate distances
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda x: math.hypot(x["x_x"]-x["x_y"], x["y_x"]-x["y_y"]), axis=1)

df.head(2) #All combination of points and the distances. 
# For example point 1 and the distance to point 2 and 3:
#id_x   x_x y_x id_y    x_y y_y distance
#1  583821.3902 6.810667e+06    2   586661.3072 6.810612e+06    2840.442084
#1  583821.3902 6.810667e+06    3   586115.1693 6.809411e+06    2615.196499

#Create a networkx graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[["id_x","id_y","distance"]].values)

#Calculate shortest path
tsp = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem
order = tsp(G=G, nodes=G.nodes, weight="weight") #A list of the point ids in the shortest order

#[1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, #22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, ..., 1]

#Create a line feature class
points = {int(i):p for i,p in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, ["OID@","SHAPE@"])}
ordered_points = [points[i].centroid for i in order]

output = r"C:\TEMP\shortest_path.shp"
line = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(ordered_points))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(line, output)
arcpy.management.DefineProjection(output, arcpy.Describe(layer).spatialReference)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the comment of BERA, if you have access to the `Network Analyst` in Pro you could use the `route analysis layer`
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/route-analysis-layer.htm#
Might be too extensive for this purpose though.

Or use `Points to Line` tool, a sort field can be used to specify the order if needed. E.g. your starting point. Otherwise points will be used in the order in which they are found.